# Why can't I interact with any views within my fragments?

Tags: xamarin, android-fragments, input, xamarin.android

^.^

I'm very new to xamarin.android and xamarin in general, and I'm finding the layout handling so much more trouble than I expected! I've finally managed to get fragments switching in and out in order to display different pages in my app, but now that that's working, the views/controls/elements such as buttons, scrollable layouts, text input, etc are not accepting input!
By that, I mean when testing, buttons do not recognise me tapping on them, my once-scrollable listview no longer scrolls when I swipe, etc.
This only applies to the views within the fragments, as the navigation drawer and other persistent default app buttons are all still fine.
I've looked for solutions everywhere but can't find anything that helps!

I'd greatly appreciate any advice/assistance, and if you require any additional information please just ask! ^.^

Thanks so much in advance! ^.^ <3

---

Code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@id/MainLayout"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

One of my fragment layouts (content_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ClothesList_ListView"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbarSize="40px"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does the views/controls/elements such as buttons, scrollable layouts, text input, etc are not accepting input mean? Could you provide more details for this?

Comment: I’ve just edited it to explain. ^.^
Basically the views are not responding to touch input on the android device. They used to before I implemented fragments, and those that are not part of the fragments (the buttons and views relating to the nav drawer, etc) still work and respond to touch perfectly well.

Comment: I checked the code you provided. No elements used for input. May i miss something?

Comment: Well in the fragment example I provided, the listview used to have noticeable visual feedback when tapping an item, but no longer does, and also shows a scroll bar that can’t be used by swiping.

Another fragment is similar but instead of a listview it has a button and that button shows no signs of response when being tapped. 

It feels like maybe something is blocking or consuming the input before it gets to the views in the fragments? But that’s just a theory, I have no way of figuring it out! >.<

Comment: I was not able to reproduce whithout more code.  Could you provide a simple code for us to reproduce the blocking?